# How to disable keyboard icon when typing on the other side of the back button, Android Nougat

Tags: keyboard, 7.0-nougat, bugs, buttons, accessibility

I'm running Android 7  Nougat.

When I type in gboard there is a small keyboard icon in the lower right corner below the keyboard. But it gets in the way when I type, bringing up the change keyboard dialog box just because my thumb touches it under the joint when I type. Is there a way of disabling it and bringing up the switch keyboard option in the notification drawer?

Is not, is this usability but be fixed in later versions of Android?

Comment: Could you provide your device model, and whether you're using a custom ROM (e.g. Lineage OS) or not?

Comment: Wiko U PULSE Lite. Android Nougat 7.0.